# How can I wipe an existing Windows partition, then reinstall Windows as a dual boot with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

So I already have a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows, but my install of Windows has amassed too many problems and hangs at startup, so I'm going to be reinstalling it. I have a TB hard drive, and about 660GB is allocated to Windows and 210GB to Ubuntu. I already backed up the stuff I need on the Windows partition. I was wondering if there's a way I could wipe the Windows partition to make it unallocated space, then resize Ubuntu to be 660 and reinstall Windows with a 210GB allocation? I'm also a bit concerned that reinstalling Windows will get rid of my grub boot screen. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: so you want to keep your Ubuntu as it is, increase the size and want to wipe windows partitions and reinstall. thats fine. can you attach a pic when you are in Ubuntu and open "GParted"? your windows and ubuntu both are in UEFI Boot mode or BIOS boot mode? also is it MBR Partitioned or GPT Partitioned?

Comment: My windows and Ubuntu are in BIOS Boot mode. My hard drive is GPT Partitioned. Here's the picture of my GParted: https://i.imgur.com/6PA6Mcs.png

Comment: as per the attached pic, there is EFI Partition. meaning UEFI Boot mode. what is sda8??

Comment: I think sda8 is a partition I made for debian a long time ago because I wanted to try it out, because debian still shows up as one of the OS I can load my pc to in grub.

Comment: I don't need sda8. My Windows version is Windows 10, but my pc came pre-installed with windows 8. I also thought I have BIOS boot because the dual boot screen looks like this person's:  https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/hardware-devices/339618d1486631026t-cant-enter-bios-when-booting-win7-ubuntu-linux-dual-boot-system-imag0320.jpg

Comment: My windows version is windows 10, but my pc was pre-installed with Windows 8, I upgraded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are with UEFI boot mode.

it is better to take the backup of your Ubuntu data also as extending ext4 / partition in GParted will take much time.

boot with bootable USB and logon to live session of Ubuntu.

1. Open GParted.
2. leave the sda2 EFI partition as it is.
3. delete the sda1, sda3, sda4 & sda5
4. now proceed with go signal to write the changes in GParted.
5. select sda9 and increase its size, it may take long time in live session.
6. after the completion of process. reboot the system.
7. Open GParted again, run in terminal `sudo sgdisk -s /dev/sda` to sort out the partitioning numbers.
8. make the unallocated space into NTFS file system.
9. shutdown the system.
10. boot with windows10 bootable USB. and do the regular installation.
11. Once windows is installed, it will directly boots to windows. you need to reinstall Grub.
12. in windows10 turn of fastboot and secureboot.
13. boot in live session of Ubuntu and then follow this highly voted Q&A [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/739431)